# run time error 438 when trying to use Openrecordset results

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have an Access project (in Office 2016) which consist of several tables and forms. Also I've designed a user login method which using it, some users must access specific records that I've tried setting them on form load event by following code. One field of my table `tbPrimary` is `initial File` which is of type attachment that some other user fill it with images\Word documents\Excel files etc. When I try fill an attachment control with recordset result I get error 438 while other controls fill properly. (error at: `Me.InitialFile = rs![Initial File]`.) Here's the code:

```vb
Public Sub Form_Load()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset ''Requires reference to Microsoft DAO x.x Library
Dim sSQL As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim nn As Double

sSQL = "SELECT MIN(tbPrimary.[ID]) As mm FROM tbPrimary WHERE Translator IS NULL"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Me.tbSearch1 = rs!mm
Else
    Me.tbSearch1 = "N/A"
End If
nn = CDbl(rs!mm)

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbPrimary WHERE ID= " & nn & ""

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
   Me!ID = rs!ID
   Me.tbInitial_Name = rs![Initial Name]
   Me.length = rs!length
   Me.Level1_Menu = rs![level1 Menu]
   Me.Level2_Menu = rs![level2 Menu]
   Me.Level3_Menu = rs![level3 Menu]
   Me.Type = rs![Type]
   Me.Description = rs!Description
   Me.tbMiningDate = rs![Mining Date]
   Me.Created = rs!Created
   Me.InitialFile = rs![Initial File]
Else
   Me.tbSearch1 = "N/A"
End If
Me.Translator.SetFocus

End Sub
```

(any solution?
Thanks in advance)

Comment: Just few tips  1) Always close the recordset after use 2) No need to set the same object again  `Set db = CurrentDb`   3) I prefer using `If Not (rs.EOF and rs.BOF)` instead of `If rs.RecordCount > 0`

Comment: Thanks in general.
I've removed a few lines from above code to take it minimal. for example I have set db to nothing one time, so i set it again, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general approach to adding attachments to an Access DB, I hope it helps.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExampleAddAccessAttachment()
    Dim db          As DAO.Database
    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsattach    As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fldattach   As DAO.Field
    Dim filepath    As String

    filepath = "SOME FILE PATH HERE"

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'Open a recordset to the table with the attachment
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from SOMETABLENAME")

    With rs
        .AddNew
        'The attachment field is a multipart field, so we can treat as a recordset
        Set rsattach = .Fields("TheAttachmentFieldName").Value

        'Get the fileData Field, this holds the data
        Set fldattach = rsattach.Fields("FileData")

        'Add a new record to this recordset, you can add multiple
        rsattach.AddNew

        'Use the load from file method to add a file to the attachment
        fldattach.LoadFromFile (filepath)

        'Update the recordset with the attachment
        rsattach.Update

        'Update the parent table recordset
        .Update
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So it adds a attachment to db. but my problem is when try to search for a certain record and show initialfile field of it in a attachment control that results error.